# Long label "..." not changing colour with the rest of the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, uicolor

I have a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell`. I change the colour of this label when the user pressed it one, and change it back when the user presses again.
This works fine for all the labels, unless this label is too long and the text get cut with "..."-LoremIpsum...

For some reason the 3 dots don't change colour together with the rest of the text

[image]

[image]

Any ideas How can I make them change with the rest of the text?
I this a bug in the framework?

```
// Configure the cell...

if([self.memberships indexOfObject:@(selectedDiscountProgram.uidValue)]!= NSNotFound){
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatOrangeColor;
    [cell.backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage rectImageWithGradientFromColor:[UIImage colorWithHex:0xDDDDDD] toColor:[UIImage colorWithHex:0xEEEEEE]]];
    [cell.memberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tjek"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.memberButton.imageEdgeInsets =UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 9.0f);
    //cell.memberButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.memberButton.frame.origin.x, cell.memberButton.frame.origin.y, 36.0, 36.0);
    [cell.memberButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else{


    cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatGrayColor;
    [cell.backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage rectImageWithGradientFromColor:[UIImage colorWithHex:0xFFFFFF] toColor:[UIImage colorWithHex:0xF0F0F0]]];
    [cell.memberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.memberButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.memberButton setTitleColor:RabatGrayColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code where you toggle the color ? I don't have any issues by implementing a change of color on selection.

Comment: @Justafinger Added the code from the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue. For some reason the "…" doesn't change colour (iOS 7.1)

Comment: Do you know if theres a bug report at Apple's?

Comment: Not that I know of, I'll be submitting one soon. In the meantime I've posted an answer below that works for me until Apple fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a boolean in your custom cell to indicate the state like isOrange, then you would have :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isOrange]) {
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatGrayColor;
    }else{
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatOrangeColor;
    }
    cell.isOrange = !cell.isOrange;
}
```

and you could add the same snippet in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    if ([cell isOrange]) {
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatOrangeColor;
    }
    else{
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = RabatGrayColor;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in custom cell add a boolean property just to know weather it is selected or not
example

in your custom cell `CustomCell.h` file

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
  @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *nameLabel;
  ....
  ....
  .... //your other properties for custom cell 
  @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSelected; //add this boolean variable
  @end
```

in `CustomCell.m`

```
@synthesize isSelected;
```

and while initialisation set it  to

```
self.isSelected = NO;//because at the beginning no cell is selected
```

in the controller, tableview delegate method just do like below

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
      if(cell == nil)
      {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
      }
      cell.nameLabel.text = @"some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text";
      //....other settings
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
      cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //initially set to balck color
      return  cell;

  } 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //get the cell of the selected index path
     if(cell.isSelected)
     {
        cell.isSelected = NO; //if it is selected set it bool to NO and change color to black
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     }
     else
     {
       cell.isSelected = YES;  //initially it is not selected so select it and set bool to YES and change the colour
       cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
     }

 }
```